# ODBC Driver Manager Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: sql-server, django, database, odbc

I have problem connecting my 64 bit laptop with a database. I am working in a django project and my database (sql server 32 bit) is in a separate server.
I have included the following in my settings file in Django.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'sales',
        'USER': '*******',
        'PASSWORD': '*********',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'HOST': 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
        },
    }
}
```

I have tried installing "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server" in my laptop. (since the server also has the same driver installed). But when I make migrations, I get an error,

```
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manag
er] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverCon
nect)')
```

Am I getting the problem due to the different versions (64 bit & 32 bit) installed in my laptop and server? If so how can I handle this without changing the entire laptop system to 32 bit?Also, I haven't installed sql server in my laptop. Should I need to install sql server in my laptop also?